# How can the ideal low pass filter from the frequency domain can be applied?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, frequency-domain

I have an image where I add a Gaussian noise. I need to use the ideal low pass filter to remove the noise  but I cannot really see any examples on the official Matlab documentation. There examples but not with images and I cannot really grasp the concept behind this filter. So could somebody explain how the ideal low pass filter can be used to remove noise?

```
image = imread('eight.tif');
imshow(image );

noisyImage = imnoise(image,'gaussian',0.02);
imshow(noisyImage);
```

[image]

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19522106/7328782 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/29235421/7328782 (low-pass is the same as a notch filter around the 0 frequency).

Comment: Is it also a filter from the frequency domain?

Comment: Yes, notice the `fft2` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the standard deviation of the noise, It's good to use a Gaussian filter with that specific standard deviation. Although in most of the cases, it's good to use Bilateral filter (`imbilatfilt`) which is a gaussian filter with some other features that **preserves the edges**.

**If you don't know what your noise is, It's best to use Wiener filter** (`[J,noise_out] = wiener2(I,[m n])`). This filter observes the frequency behavior of the image and looks for a special pattern which is statistically consistent with noise. In other word, it estimate the noise of image and filter that specific noise for you. `noise_out` is the estimates of the additive noise power and m,n are the sizes of the filter's kernel (which I suggest something like 5*5 or 7*7).

Of course there are some other filtering methods including handmade ones, but those need more effort and lots of trial and error.